# Stylua programmatically remove single string / table parentheses?

Tags: lua, formatting

I ran stylua over my project while not being in my project base, so it didn't get the coresponding `stylua.toml`.

The formatting I used to use was no parenthesis on single string and table calls. Re-running stylua with the correct `stylua.toml` updates all styles correctly but keeps the parentheses on single table calls. I guess for safety reasons.

I was stupid enough not to commit a bunch of changes that were going on prior to formatting the whole project. So reverting to a commit prior to that formatting is unfortunately not a real option.

The question I now end up with is if  there is a safe way to pragmatically remove parenthesis on single strings and tables in a project?

Comment: According to the [StyLua Readme](https://github.com/JohnnyMorganz/StyLua#options), setting `call_parentheses = "None"` should work.

Comment: Oh wow so simple, I must have missed that. It does the job, thank you!